# How to get rows from one data frame based on another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two files which are.csv format, which doesn't have any column names and they are nonuniform size. I want to select the row in 1st csv file which contains at least one same value or word as the 2nd csv file. I tried below one:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 =pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Airtop_routings/ASEAN_20170601_VST_0000_without$.csv",header=None,low_memory=False,dtype=object)

df1.set_index(df1[0])

df2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Airtop_routings/Singapore Waypoints.csv",header=None,dtype=object)
df3=list(df2[0])
df1.loc[df1.isin(df3)]
```

but I got the error like below:

**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'**

**Ex: 1st csv file**

```
Apple mango parrot snake 100
Mango grapes tiger lion 200 snake bear
tiger apple jackal
```

**2nd CSV file**

```
apple                                      
tiger             
lion
```

By using 2nd csv file I want to select rows in the 1st csv file. Anyone help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df2['column2'])
df = df1[df1["column1"].str.contains(pat)]
```

Comment: Dear @jezrael, I don't have any column names in my files. To create columns my files have at least 100 columns. How to select without column names.

Comment: @AthotaSrinivas - OK, so hoe working `pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df2[0])
df = df1[df1[0].str.contains(pat)]` ?

Comment: I got an error like this:                                                                      
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: @AthotaSrinivas - Try `df = df1[df1[0].astype(str).str.contains(pat)]`

Comment: I didn't get the correct answer it's just giving numbers from 1 to 140 in 1st row

Comment: @AthotaSrinivas - Are data confidental? If not, is possible send me csv to my email in my profile?